# 2 javascript object event handlers interaction

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, events

I want to do the following

```
let o1
let o2

o1.call()
  .on('x', function(result1) {

    o2.call()
      .on('y', function(result2) {  }) //expecting a value returned 

    result1 += result2 //modify result1
  })
  .next(function(result1) { 
    // do something with modified result1      
  })
```

Above is just pseudocode.

I want to modify result1 inside on('x'), does it wait for o2.on('y')?

How can I modify result1 with result2 in on('x')?

Effectively I want something like the following:

```
let o1
let o2

o1.call()
  .on('x', function(result1) {

    result1 += o2() //sync, but I have no control over this o2 external library/ object that was designed to be async

  })
  .next(function(result1) { 
    // do something with modified result1      
  })
```

Comment: no the code doesn't run, it is just a pseudocode. I wanted to modify result1 (what im trying to achieve)

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. And yes, it should be possible. But why do you ask? Where should the problem be?

Comment: the problem is o2 might take a long time to trigger event 'y'

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `result1` inside `function(result2) {  }`:

```
.on('y', function(result2) {
    result1 += result2
})
```

Comment: This plus moving the `.next()` code from being a promise on the `.on('x')` to being a promise on the inner `.on('y')` so that can utilize the modified value as intended.

Comment: thanks I'll give it a go. I was under the impression .next( ) will run before .on('y')